# The POM for com.google.code.morphia:morphia:jar:1.00-SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available

Tags: java, mongodb, maven, pom.xml, morphia

The POM for com.google.code.morphia:morphia:jar:1.00-SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available

```
<scm>
   <connection>scm:svn:svn://morphia.googlecode.com/svn/mavenrepo/</connection>
          <developerConnection>scm:svn:svn://morphia.googlecode.com/svn/mavenrepo/</developerConnection>
</scm>
```

Answer (score 10):

The Morphia functionality will be merged into the official Java driver, therefore there won't be a 1.0 release.

Take the 0.99.1-SNAPSHOT - this is the latest version and includes all recent bugfixes. This should work in your POM:

```
    <repository>
        <id>morphia</id>
        <url>http://morphia.googlecode.com/svn/mavenrepo/</url>
    </repository>

    ...

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
        <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.morphia</groupId>
        <artifactId>morphia</artifactId>
        <version>0.99.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
```

**UPDATE 1**: There's now a fork with a stable release, which includes quite some bugfixes: https://github.com/jmkgreen/morphia

We've switched to it and haven't seen any regressions (it just requires a global search and replace, since the namespace has changed). IMHO, this is currently the best solution.

**UPDATE 2**: MongoDB Inc. has now picked up Morphia again. You can find it at https://github.com/mongodb/morphia - this is what you should use now!

Comment: but we are using maven and in maven repo its only 0.91 version. So is there any way to add alternate address for morphia repo in pom.xml as we already have one repo for project and our maven is pointing to it. also we can not copy jay directly from morphia repo as it leads to versioning problem. So we have to point that to morphia repo where jar is present.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you correctly. You'll need to add the Morphia repository - I've added it in the post above.

Comment: In case someone is interested in following de integration with the offical driver, here's a Jira issue about that: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/JAVA-580

Comment: Just to keep this answer current- the current "official" version of morphia can be found [here, on GitHub](http://github.com/mongodb/morphia)

Comment: but where is the JAR on github?

Comment: There are no binaries on GitHub, but you can download it from Maven Central: http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.mongodb.morphia%7Cmorphia%7C0.105%7Cjar However, I'd strongly advise to use Maven, Gradle, or something similar for dependency management

Comment: Okay so i was trying this way to get morphia to use. The repository url is discontinued by google. After looking around for a while, i found the best possible fix http://www.foobaracademy.com/morphia-hello-world-example/